# Can't query the Windows Event Log 'Forwarded Events' with dates

Tags: windows, powershell, events, logging, event-log

We're trying to create a PowerShell function to query the Windows Event Log for events that happened between two dates.
The following code works fine when querying a custom log or a standard log:

```
$FilterXML = @"
<QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path='$LogName'>
        <Select Path='$LogName'>
            *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2017-04-17T09:48:24.000Z' and 
            @SystemTime&lt;='2017-04-19T09:50:24.999Z']]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
"@
Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $FilterXML
```

We've set up our Windows Server 2012 to collect events from other servers, like a Windows Server 2008 R2. When checking the events in the Event Viewer we can see that they are available in the log `Forwarded Events`. When querying them without a date in the GUI or in PowerShell this works perfectly fine.

However. when we want to query that same 'Forwarded Events' log in the GUI or in PowerShell by adding a date From and a date To selection, it's simply saying there are no matches found. Which is incorrect because when we check these events they all have the `TimeCreated` property with a date that is between those dates.

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
```

When running the same query on the source computer where the events are created it works fine with the dates. On the Collector server, when selecting only events from the last 7 days or 24 hours, this works fine too. So it has something to do with the forwarding of the events and the `DateTime` object in them I guess. We've checked Regional Settings on both server, they are the same Dutch (Belgium) for date formats.

**Example event where the date can't be used:**

```
Message              : johofman - Script ended
Id                   : 199
Version              : 
Qualifiers           : 0
Level                : 4
Task                 : 1
Opcode               : 
Keywords             : 36028797018963968
RecordId             : 768
ProviderName         : My script name
ProviderId           : 
LogName              : My log name
ProcessId            : 
ThreadId             : 
MachineName          : SERVER.domain.net
UserId               : 
TimeCreated          : 19/04/2017 16:02:56
ActivityId           : 
RelatedActivityId    : 
ContainerLog         : c:\windows\system32\winevt\logs\forwardedevents.evtx
MatchedQueryIds      : {}
Bookmark             : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventBookmark
LevelDisplayName     : Information
OpcodeDisplayName    : Info
TaskDisplayName      : 
KeywordsDisplayNames : {Classic}
Properties           : {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty}
```

Is there a reason why this is working for all Event Logs but not for `Forwarded Events`?

Event Logging has been configured as described [here](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/centralizing-windows-logs/).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Get-WinEvent -LogName ForwardedEvents ?

Comment: Gives me the correct result, also when using this in `-FilterXML` but not when adding dates.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying with `-filterHashTable` ? For example:

```
$filter = @{ 
                    Path   = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\ForwardedEvents.evtx"
                    StartTime = get-date '2017-04-17T09:48:24.000Z'
                    EndTime   = get-date '2017-04-19T09:50:24.999Z'                  
                    }
```

Then

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter
```

Comment: Same message I'm afraid, `no events were found that match the specified selection criteria`. Really weird. because querying without dates gives me the Events and I can see the correct dates in them...

Comment: Did you try playing with the dates, i.e. the previous day until the next day?

Comment: Yes I did, first thing I tried actually. It's working fine with the same dates on the remote source server but not on the collector server when changing the Path to ForwardedEvents. When trying 24 hours ago this works too, only not between dates.

Comment: More info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/82dbe515-4dfe-4802-b65a-35720e667b14/cant-query-the-windows-event-log-forwarded-events-with-dates?forum=winserver8gen)